# Cannot find name 'keyof'

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm trying to use the keyof keyword in `typescript` but it seems to be not found.
I'm using `typescript 3.5.2` with `angular 7.2.2`
Thanks in advance.

```
export class Functions {

  static ListObjectProperties(): string[] {
        let array = keyof Foo;
        return array;
  }
}
```

I get "Cannot find name 'keyof'"

Comment: Add the code. It really depends where you are trying to use it.

Comment: Angular 7.2 only supports typescript 3.2, use that version, also you need to add the code

Comment: @Robertgarcia `keyof` has been in ts long before 3.2. My guess it OP is using `keyof` in a value position, but without code it's hard to say.

Comment: Not saying the ts version is breaking it, but for sure Angular wont compile with TS 3.5.2, thats all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only use `keyof` in a type context.
For instance:

```
interface Foo { aProperty: unknown }

const x: keyof Foo = "aProperty"
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response